# how to update placeholder text in odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

let say i have this in the view

```
field name='acct_ids' 
on_change="on_change_acct_ids(acct_ids)" 
placeholder="All"

def on_change_acct_ids(self,cr,user,ids,acct_ids,context=None):
        return {'placeholder': {'acct_ids': 'someplaceholder'}}
```

whenever the field 'acct_ids' change, my goal is that I want to update the placeholder text but I can't find any way to do it. Hope you can help. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that's possible on server-side.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think There is a way to do that but you can use label to do this 
put multiple label and using `attrs` you can hide and show the target label according to field value.